# How to create columns dynamically in MySQL using python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a large CSV file with 50,000 integer values for each record.

How do I insert them into a MySQL table? I don't understand the schema for this.

Comment: 50k columns in table, sounds like poor design. Anyway MySQL supports up to 4096 columns per table.

Comment: How many records are there? What do you want to do with this data? Why do you want to put it in MySQL, or any SQL database for that matter?

Comment: You may create a table dynamically and then insert the values. For this use the advanced topic of [prepared statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) may help.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html

Comment: I have about 50,0000 random binary values. I am doing XOR operation and finding the distance with each other. And the result is stored in an integer format. Now I need a way to store these distances in a matrix or any organized table format and do further analysis.